# jQuery find elements of class name within same container

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, user-controls, jquery-selectors

I have a UserControl in MVC which may be repeated many times on the page.

Say I had something like the following:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="enableTextBox">edit</a>"
    <input type="text" class="comments" readonly="readonly" />
</div>

<div>
    <a href="#" class="enableTextBox">edit</a>"
    <input type="text" class="comments" readonly="readonly" />
</div>

<div>
    <a href="#" class="enableTextBox">edit</a>"
    <input type="text" class="comments" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
```

How can I find the `class="comments"` element which is **in the same div** as the `class="enableTextBox"` link, in the onclick event of the link?

Is this a sensible way of handling element Id conflicts? Is there a better way? How secure would it be in terms of running in an enterprise app and being certain of data consistency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery's `.siblings()` method is one way:

```
$('.enableTextBox').click(function() {
    var $comments = $(this).siblings('.comments');
    return false;  // Prevent page refresh
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

There are lots of traversal methods available in jQuery:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

**EDIT:** Added `return false;` to prevent the link from refreshing the page.

Here's an example you can test: http://jsfiddle.net/MZEmP/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".enableTextBox").click(function() {
   $(".comments", $(this).parent())  //this will get you the comments associated with the anchor you click on
})
```